# C# to calculate factorial

Tags: c#, factorial

I have this code that gets an input from the user and calculate its factorial and the factorial for less than the input number, but I keep getting the factorial for the first number only and the rest is 0. It should be like this: For example, if the input is 5:

5! = 120

4! = 24

3! = 6

2! = 4

1! = 1

How do I make the loop go throw all the numbers below the input number?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace multiple_factorials
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, n;

            Console.WriteLine(".....................[Application 1].....................\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to get its factorial: ");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            n = num; // Assign n to num

            while (num > 0)
            {
                for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
                {
                   n *= i;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0}! = {1}\n", num, n);
                num--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do you have a question?

Comment: edited sorry i forgot the question

Comment: Its still not clear. What is your question? (use '?' sign at the end of the sentence)

Comment: Run it in the debugger, inspect the variables, and it should become clear what the problem is...

Comment: Put  `n = num; // assign n to num` inside the while loop

Comment: please, don't downvote, the guy has a valid question for him.

Comment: Just as a side note, should 2! not be 2 x 1 = 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426715/factorial-of-n-numbers-using-c-sharp-lambda

Comment: It would be nice to calculate each factorial only one time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move `n = num;` inside the `while` loop:

```
while (num > 0)
{
    n = num;
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        n *= i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0}! = {1}\n", num, n);
    num--;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the `simplest` solutions `are the best`.  +1

Answer (score 8):

To answer you question now you have acctually posted it:

> My question is How to make the loop go throw all the numbers below the input number?

With a loop

`for(int i = input; i > 0; i--)`

Will count down from input (lets say 5) to 1 `{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`

then you simply multiply together

```
int result = 1;
for(int i = input; i > 0; i--) 
    result *= i;
```

Proof:
    int input = 4;
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = input; i > 0; i--) 
        result *= i;

```
Console.WriteLine("Result=" + result);
```

> Output: 24

A better way Using Recusion

```
public int Factorial(int f)
{
    if(f == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return f * Factorial(f-1); 
}
```

so calling Factorial(5) gives a result of 120 etc.

Comment: Clearly this does not answer the question but get all the votes

Comment: It does now Eric, i answered before OP acctually posted a question. His OP was just "Here is code".

Comment: the answer is as Eric said : just move n=num; inside the while loop and it works. ( Solved )

Comment: Two things. First, the validation should be if it is less than 2. The second, use long instead of int. For example, for Factorial (13) it returns an incorrect value.

Comment: Recursion is not a better way when an iterative approach exists.

Comment: For future readers, Don't do what Alex said they did. If the OP has not asked a question, then flag for clarification and move on. Don't guess.

Answer (score 8):

You've included `System.Linq` so I've put a LINQ  solution:

```
 int n = 5;

 // result == 120
 int result = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate(1, (p, item) => p * item);
```

However, LINQ is *overkill* here, and the *for loop* is more readable. To print out all the lines:

```
int num = 5;

String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  Enumerable.Range(1, num)
    .Reverse()
    .Select((index) =>
      String.Format("Factorial of {0}! = {1}\n",
                    index,
                    Enumerable.Range(1, index).Aggregate(1, (p, item) => p * item))));

Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: _"You've included System.Linq so I've put a LINQ solution:"_ - just so you know Visual Studio automatically adds `using System.Linq` to the top of new classes and more importantly when creating a _console app_

Comment: This is incredibly slow and complex for what it's accomplishing

Answer (score 2):

Two things;

Change your `int i = n - 1` to `int i = num` and assign your `n` to `1` just before your for loop.

```
while (num > 0)
{
     n = 1;
     for (int i = num; i > 0; i--)
     {                    
           n *= i;
     }           
     Console.WriteLine("Factorial of {0}! = {1}\n", num, n);
     num--;
}
```

Result will be;

> Please Enter A Number To Get Its factorial 5
>
> Factorial of 5! = 120
>
> Factorial of 4! = 24
>
> Factorial of 3! = 6
>
> Factorial of 2! = 2
>
> Factorial of 1! = 1

Answer (score 2):

As a definition, 0! == 1. There are several ways to deal with this, from the shortest to the most clever, so that you get the sequence: 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120... I think that Linq gives the shortest/cleanest code.

```
int f(i) => Enumerable.Range(1,i<1?1:i).Aggregate((f,x)=>f*x);
```

Other alternatives, tho less clean, wouold be:

```
int f(i) => Enumerable.Range(1,Math.Max(1,i).Aggregate((f,x)=>f*x);

int f(i) => Enumerable.Range(1,i+(int)Math.Pow(0,i)).Aggregate((f,x)=>f*x);
```

Comment: I mean, if brevity over performance is the goal, then _technically_ `Enumerable.Range(1,++i).Aggregate((f,x)=>f*x)/i;` is shorter. (Please don't ever do this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function for factorial calculation
sample code is:

```
public static int  fak(int number)
{
    if(number==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return number*(fak(number-1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a value n>=0");
int UserInput=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int factorial = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= UserInput; i++) 
{
    factorial *= i;//factorial=factorial * i
}
Console.WriteLine(factorial);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

this is my code snippet for factorial calculation

```
ulong GetFactorialResult(ulong number)
{
    if (number > 0 && number != 1)
    {
        checked
        {
            return (number * (number - 1)) * GetFactorialResult(number - 2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).