# Probability calculator in c#

Tags: c#, calculator, probability

I've got a programing problem.

I've been trying to do something like a probability calculator in c#, for that I need a *certain type of factorial*. I know how to program *factorial*, but I need

> sum of all the factorials from zero to some given number.

Suppose the input number is some constant `r`, what I want is:

```
0! + 1! +2! + ... + (r-1)! + r!
```

This is what I've got so far, but still does not work:

```
double a, j, k = 1, sum = 1, l = 1;

for (a = 1; a <= f; a ++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= a; j++)
    {
        l = k * j;
    }

    sum = sum + l;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Where's the factorial calculation? `k` is always 1 so at the end of the loop `l` is simply equal to `a`. Split your code into functions, make sure the `factorial` function works and only then try to use it for other calculations

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you expect just based on certain factors like k=1. You multiple k by j, but k never changes from 1. f doesn't exist. This needs code needs some work before you'll be ready to even ask for help with the problem at hand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027000/c-sharp-to-calculate-factorial

Answer (score 1):

One simple `for` loop is enough. Since `factorial` grows fast, let's use `BigInteger` type;
however, if you want, you can change all `BigInteger` into `double`:

```
using System.Numerics;

...

// 0! + 1! + 2! + ... + value!
public static BigInteger MyFunc(int value) {
  if (value < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));

  BigInteger result = 1;
  BigInteger factorial = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i) 
    result += (factorial *= i);

  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] tests = new int[] {
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  tests.Select(x => $"{x} => {MyFunc(x),4}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
0 =>    1
1 =>    2
2 =>    4
3 =>   10
4 =>   34
5 =>  154
6 =>  874
7 => 5914
```